# Ruby on rails app deploy to apache without passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I am running the following versions of ruby, gem, rails on ubuntu 13.10 :

==> ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

==> gem --version
1.8.23

==> rails --version
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
Rails 4.1.0

Is there a good way to deploy a ruby on rails app to an apache2 server without using phusion passenger?

Comment: I guess you need a application server like passenger to deploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

Then your only option is to choose some other application server

- [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma)
- [Unicorn](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn)
- [Thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/)

This [link](https://www.engineyard.com/articles/rails-server) might help

Answer (score 0):

[Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) is a solid solution for running Rails app.
checkout this [tutorial](https://github.com/teambox/teambox/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu-using-Apache-and-Unicorn) to set up Unicorn + Apache